# Can we use "I wish I saw" for a past situation?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, tenses, conditionals

In the series F.R.I.E.N.D.S, Joey makes a pass at Rachel because, according to himself, he saw Rachel first. When Rachel rejects and convinces Joey that this would be a mistake, Joey says,

- "Yeah you're right. But man I wish I saw Phoebe first"

instead of

- "Man I wish I had seen Phoebe first".

This is only one of the many occasions in which I've seen people avoid using past perfect and use simple past instead. Sometimes they use "simple past + would" structure because they are generalizing a statement, but in this particular situation and many others I'm sure they are talking about one particular event in the past.

P.S. I've asked a similar question before regarding whether the past perfect tense is considered formal, but I didn't have an actual example then and therefore couldn't get a clear answer.

Comment: The example is a helpful illustration of the previously asked question, but it doesn't change it substantially; it could have been edited into that question.

Comment: @jsw29 Hi. yes, but I assumed not as many people would see it that way. I'm not exactly sure how edits work here or if anyone will get a notification that a certain message has been edited or something. That's why I created a whole new post with an actual example

Comment: But that's the wrong way to go about things. Duplicates make sitre searches far more difficult, so deliberate ones are thoughtless.  Edits ensure promotion up the 'recent' pile. // I'd say it's ungrammatical, but people _will_ keep playing the regionalism card.